# QWC Docker - run service on own URL

Tags: qwc2

I have installed qwc-docker on Ubuntu 18.04 and it is running quiet good. Now I want to run the service on my URL from my company and not on localhost anymore. Which config-file do I have to change? And what exactly do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

The nginx configuration file tells docker on which port to make the website available in the host machine. You just have to route traffic to that port (make use of that port).

Maybe you have a nginx instance configured as a reverse proxy? You add a new configuration using the host IP and port.

Depending on your setup you may also need to edit postgres configuration files and `.env`.